# swagger listing api for worknik

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I have used `swagger-express` npm module to configure api-documentation parallel to my server so it help devs to keep track of all apis.

What I have folder structure is

```
/
/api
    swagger/
           swagger.json
           swagger.yml
/swagger /*Having all the index file and configs as given their like public dir*/
```

My middle-ware configuration is like this

```
var swagger = require('swagger-express');
app.use(swagger.init(app, {
    apiVersion    : '1.0',
    swaggerVersion: '1.0',
    swaggerURL    : '/swagger',
    swaggerJSON   : 'api/swagger/swagger.json',
    swaggerUI     : './swagger/',
    basePath      : 'http://localhost:1222',
    info          : {
        title      : 'swagger-express sample app',
        description: 'Swagger + Express = {swagger-express}'
    },
    apis          : ['api/swagger/swagger.yml'],
    middleware    : function (req, res) {}
}));
```

My server is running at port `1222`. Now though the SwaggerUI is loaded successfully but its reading api's from wordnik's domain.

1. How would it read apis from my `swagger.yml`
2. If I am mentioning the `swagger.yml` then whats the relevancy and use of `swagger.json`
3. What is `discoverURL` in SwaggerUI? If I am mentioning my json path (`http://localhost:1222/swagger/`) in that it ends with error like 'discoveryUrl basePath must be a URL.'

Is their any way I can list all apis in parallel to server? so It can be tested as well? I want it with swagger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey just try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-swagger

npm install hapi-swagger --save

npm install inert --save

npm install vision --save

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Inert = require('inert');
const Vision = require('vision');
const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger');
const Pack = require('./package');

const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000
    });

const options = {
    info: {
            'title': 'Test API Documentation',
            'version': Pack.version,
        }
    };

server.register([
    Inert,
    Vision,
    {
        'register': HapiSwagger,
        'options': options
    }], (err) => {
        server.start( (err) => {
           if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
            }
        });
    });

server.route(Routes);
```